# can not build mozilla firefox with mozilla-build?

Tags: firefox

in order to try to build from source code mozilla-firefox I try to set up a Windows Firefox build environment like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJzYZGnXE5A)
but instead of **Visual Studio 2012** I used **Visual Studio 2013 ultimate .update 5**.

On [the mozilla site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Windows_Prerequisites)
they recommend **VS Community 2013**.

After that I get the firefox source code using the bundle as in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j0McmMfBIo0)

The problem is that whene I try to build the Firefox with the commend `mach build` like [in here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJMuBzBuCBc)

I get lot of warnings and the firefox does not built :

```
 0:01.71 c:\mozilla-build\mozmake\mozmake.EXE -f client.mk -s
 0:09.67 Adding client.mk options from :
 0:09.67     MOZ_OBJDIR=c:/mozilla-central/obj-i686-pc-mingw32
 0:09.67     OBJDIR=c:/mozilla-central/obj-i686-pc-mingw32
 0:11.79 Elapsed: 0.02s; From dist/branding: Kept 15 existing; 
 .
 .
 .
 0:31.52 buildid.h
 0:31.54 source-repo.h
 0:35.22 expr: syntax error
 0:35.25 expr: syntax error
 .
 .
 .
 2:03.95 mozmake.EXE[3]: *** [compile] Error 2
 2:03.95 c:/mozilla-central/config/rules.mk:557: recipe for target 'default' failed
 2:03.95 mozmake.EXE[2]: *** [default] Error 2
 2:03.97 c:/mozilla-central/client.mk:398: recipe for target 'realbuild' failed
 2:03.97 mozmake.EXE[1]: *** [realbuild] Error 2
 2:03.97 client.mk:171: recipe for target 'build' failed
 2:03.97 mozmake.EXE: *** [build] Error 2
 2:04.03 233 compiler warnings present.
```

What is the problem and how do I fix it?